# Uploading and IntelliJ project to host site

Tags: intellij-idea, hosting

I have tried to upload an IntelliJ project to a host site with all the file in the correct place I think. This is in the web inf classes folder I have the hibernate.xml and struts.xml along with the classes taken from the project. I have put all the jsp pages into the public-HTML. But these are in folder which was the way they were mapped when  just running on local host. Should these jsp pages be taken out the folder and be in the same location as the index.jsp ?  So when view the site I get the index page but I can't view the register user page as it says it can't find it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is your goal to deplay project or to develop it on remote machine?

Comment: to deploy the project this is now the error i am receiving java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Comment: What application server do you use? You should upload the target Artifact directory. If the Artifact can be deployed and works on the local server, the same should work when uploaded to the remote server.

Comment: i have deployed it through my hosting company uploading from the out/deployement folder. Do I still need to edit the artifact in intellij?

Comment: You should be able to deploy it from the `out/artifacts` folder. If it works on the local server, it will most likely work on the remote server as well when deployed this way.

Comment: i have tried using the out/artifacts folder and no such luck still the same error. do you think the hosting company is looking for it to be deployed as a war file?